# Rspec test yielding a method object from object constructor

Tags: ruby, rspec, yield

I have the following code:

```
def initialize
  yield method(:fulfill), method(:reject) if block_given?
end
```

I cannot test that the actual values `method(:fulfill)` and `method(:reject)` are yielded, because I do not have access to the object yet when the values are yielded.

Therefore I want to test it like this:

```
expect do |b|
  PurePromise.new(&b)
end.to yield_with_args(PurePromise.instance_method(:fulfill), PurePromise.instance_method(:reject))
```

However, an `UnboundMethod` doesn't equal an `Method`, even if it refers to the same method.

Is there any way of transforming the yielding values by calling `unbind` before matching against the arguments of `yield_with_args`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using rspec 3's [composable matchers](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers).

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_bound_method_of do |unbound_method|
  match do |bound_method|
    bound_method.unbind == unbound_method
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.alias_matcher :a_bound_method_of, :be_a_bound_method_of

expect do |b|
  PurePromise.new(&b)
end.to yield_with_args(
           a_bound_method_of(PurePromise.instance_method(:fulfill)),
           a_bound_method_of(PurePromise.instance_method(:reject))
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of one way, but it involves calling a private method, so it feels a bit hacky

```
subject = PurePromise.allocate
expect do |b|
  subject.send(:initialize, &b)
end.to yield_with_args(subject.method(:fulfill), subject.method(:reject))
```

Any better solutions would be appreciated.